# How can I autocomplete fields in Alation?

Tags: automation, alation

I work for a company that has a lot of data. Sometimes we need to fill in the same information in more than one equal field.

For example, imagine that the column "person_id", which appears in table X, in table Y and in table Z, and that this column has the same description: It is the identification of the person that comes from such and such a rule, that has this and that logic.

The problem I'm facing in Alation is this... we have many identical columns in different tables and sometimes we need to copy and paste the same description. But, the biggest problem is that we have more than 1000 tables with some similar columns and automating this process would make more sense for column padding.

I'm a little lost on what I should do, would it make sense to create some automation, in python, to autocomplete? Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

At the moment, what I've tried is talking to people who are more experienced in using Alation, who have told me that the platform has no solution for this. I even thought about using it in composer, but I couldn't go very far, I don't think it made much sense to do that. One of the ideas I had was to use python, but I don't know where to start because I'm a beginner and would like some idea where to start or if there is any platform that automates column filling in Alation.